# In Win32, How can I detect if a HWND is a dialog?

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, hwnd

In a pure C Win32 application, how can I detect if a `HWND` is [a dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetClassLong()` to find its class atom. Unless it was created with a custom window class (very unlikely), its class will be `WC_DIALOG`.

```
if ( WC_DIALOG == MAKEINTATOM(GetClassLong(hWnd, GCW_ATOM)) )
{
    /* this is a dialog */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dialogs have a standard class name of `"#32770"`. You can use [`GetClassName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname)/[`RealGetWindowClass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-realgetwindowclassw) <sup>1</sup> to check if a window is using a dialog class.

<sup>1: see [What makes RealGetWindowClass so much more real than GetClassName?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101231-00/?p=11863)</sup>

Comment: That's just the class atom in string form though :)